# Google Signin not working with Low-Code automated testing tools

Tags: authentication, firebase-authentication, automated-tests, lowcode

I am trying to set up low-code automated testing or my web app. I am specifically looking at Autify and Browserstack. These tools, in one of the various ways, drive the browser while executing the test. This doesn't seem to work well with Google signin flow. Upon entering the username, Google signin throws this error:

"This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can try again to sign in."

I tried Autify, Browserstack, saucelabs, bugbug and a few other tools, and all have the same problem. Is there a tool that can handle this? Is there a browser setting or something these tools allow you to set that will reduce the security requirements?

I am considering add username-password based auth (e.g. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) to my test instance, but that feels like a hacky workaround.

Comment: Hi If your issue is related to app automate you can check this document https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/advanced-features/setup-google-account
Else, you can  raise a support ticket by sending an email to support@browserstack.com or via this link, browserstack.com/contact#technical-support.

Comment: Turns out that most of these low-code testing tools cannot handle google signin as google's signin flows seem to block automated signin attempts. I added username/password authentication to my app for testing purposes and that works just fine.